# Como listar o nome dos arquivos que estão no diretório?

Tags: java, arquivo

A saída do método a seguir é:

> C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\arquivos\nomedoarquivo.jpg

Como posso obter apenas o *nomedoarquivo.jpg*
em formato String? Tentei usar `FileUtils` mas como saída obtive isso:

*����.ELs��/�G������Yos���e�([��E��v���^�C�O���W�ݭ�:
��Zj���2+�յ����v����[{޶�J*

```
public static void getImgs(String path){
    File file = new File(path);
    File[] arquivos = file.listFiles();

    try {
        for (File arquivo : arquivos) {
            System.out.println(arquivo);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Já tentou printar o nome do arquivo? `arquivo.getName()`, `arquivo.getCanonicalPath()`, `arquivo.getAbsolutePath()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando você usa o `System.out.println(arquivo);` na verdade está imprimindo o `getPath()`.

[segue a documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#toString())

Para imprimir o nome, tente assim:

```
public static void getImgs(String path){
    File file = new File(path);
    File[] arquivos = file.listFiles();

    try {
        for (File arquivo : arquivos) {
            System.out.println(arquivo.getName());
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nossa, solução bastante simples. Diferente do encontrei por ai. Excelente.

Comment: Mas é estranho ter como resultado na sua tentativa, @Bruno, aquela aglomeração de caracteres quebrados. Esse deveria ser o retorno do `getPath()`?

Comment: Não entendi o porque dos caracteres, mas estava usando (por recomendação) a classe FileUtils para converter o File para String e então usar split na String para obter apenas o nome do arquivo. Talvez eu estivesse pegando o conteúdo do arquivo e não seu path.

Comment: Só pra saber, qual sistema operacional você está utilizando?